# Use CursorAdapter bindView() to set data

Tags: android, android-cursor

I know that `bindView()` can be called by the system multiple times, and I can't do anything about it.

I want to set some variable values inside `bindView()`, like

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        int salary = cursor.getInt(1);

        MainActivity.totalSalary += salary; //totalSalary is a static field        
}
```

however, because it's called multiple times the data gets corrupted and invalid.

I can't think of any workaround to this.. any idea?

Comment: In the `swapCursor` method of your adapter you can loop over the cursor and count the salary

Comment: you can get it calculated outside MainActivity.totalSalary += salary;  also from database itself

Comment: @RalphBergmann I use `swapCursor` only when the activity is restarted. (that is, `onRestart()` is called). In other times I create the CursorAdapter from newly fetched records. So basically when the app is created, I won't be able to calculate `totalSalary`. Edit: I actually meant that I'm using changeCursor(), not swapCursor(). Is this critical?

Comment: @Pavan What do you mean "outside MainActivity.totalSalary += salary;"? And yes.. I'm using an `AsyncTask` I called `ChangeCursorTask` that uses `rawQuery()` and calls `changeCursor` in its `onPostExecute()`. I guess I can execute another thread from there that will fetch data from the database again to get the total salary. I just wanted to spare all that.. Isn't there a better approach?

Comment: can you add data fetching code

Comment: `changeCursor` is the better one because it closes the cursor automatically for you

Comment: Please don't create a new CursorAdapter for every new fetched data. Usually you create your adapter once with your Activity/Fragment. If you get new data from you DB/ContentProvider you just call `changeCursor`. There is no need to create a new adapter

Comment: @RalphBergmann thanks for the tip... I changed my code because of that. Another question: Should I check if an sql table exists before calling SELECT commands on it? The later has less code but does throw an SQLiteException, which I can live with, but is it legit?

Comment: I never checked it. But if you are new to the SQLite stuff on Android take a look at [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html). It makes it much easier to access SQLite. But at the end a good SQL knowledge is alway a good idea.

Comment: Here is a good [code lab about room](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence)